# I have an Apache + PHP server that I can upload code. Can I use languages other than PHP to do server-side coding?

Tags: php, javascript, apache, clojure, programming-languages

If your server only has support for Apache, what are server-side scripting languages you can use other than PHP?

Comment: Why my question is downvoted and a answer that does not answer it is upvoted? I suppose you did not understand me?

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear...

Comment: I just wrote an edit also, but I think this edit here is better (concise).

Comment: I've edited, I think it is shorter and clearer now. To put it simple, I'm developing a site to be hosted in a server with XAMPP. My files will be hosted on /xampp/htdocs/mysite. Can I do server-side coding with languages other than PHP?

Comment: This might help you: http://briancarper.net/blog/510/deploying-clojure-websites

Comment: It is indeed something I have been looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a Apache + PHP server that you can upload code to and you can install Lisp etc on, but you can't reconfigure Apache?

The best answer would really be to talk to whoever controls your server and get them to enable the appropriate mods or mod_proxy-ing to whichever language or application you want.

But if this isn't an option, you could implement a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) in PHP that passes all calls through to your Lisp application.

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. Might I ask, how could that small proxy be implemented?

Comment: Have a google for "reverse proxy php"

Answer (score 3):

Apache is usually compiled with support for *modules*. PHP is one such module that is generally configured within your `apache.conf` file. If you have access to edit your apache.conf, you are able to `include` other modules that exist on the system already, or modules that you add to the system.

Examples of another module you can add would be `mod_wsgi`, allowing you to serve from `python` files.

What you want to search for, is `apache modules`.

Answer (score 2):

Apache supports a lot of languages besides PHP, you can check all of them here and how to get it: http://projects.apache.org/indexes/language.html

Most of these language can be supported at the same time, you can install them by using modules or scripts in cgi-bin-

Answer (score 1):

The Apache feature you were describing before question edit runs PHP files via a module. Another commonly used apache module is CGI, which allows you to use any language, but it's discouraged because of performance and security.

You're better off using FastCGI (which isn't normal CGI) or similar. If you can't make any modifications to the apache config file, you're boned. No non-php auto-evaluating scripts in public_html.